# Can I use one memory pool for multiple vectors?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

Say I have a STL compliant(ish) allocator. I want multiple instances (millions) of an STL container (`std::vector`) to use the same instance of that allocator (we'll assume thread safety is guaranteed). Will this implementation work as expected?

```
MemoryPool<int> mypool;
std::vector<std::vector<int, MemoryPool<int>>> myvec;
myvec.assign(BIG_NUMBER, std::vector<int, MemoryPool<int>>{1, mydefault, mypool});
```

I also attempted:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int, MemoryPool<int>>> myvec;
myvec.assign(BIG_NUMBER, {mydefault});
```

...and got the same memory usage.

The problem is that my memory usage is blowing up with this implementation.  From ~12MB with the default allocator to ~4GB with the memory pool allocator.

I'm assuming what's happening is that each vector is getting a new instance of my memory allocator, resulting in a lot of wasted storage due to the large block size of the memory pool.  I reason that if they all used the same memory pool instance, the memory usage would be closer to the default allocator.

For reference, I'm using this memory pool implementation: https://github.com/cacay/MemoryPool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use said `MemoryPool` as an allocator for `std::vector`, since it is intended for fixed-size allocations:

> A memory pool has just a few disadvantages:
>
> - Objects have a fixed size which must be known beforehand. This is usually not a
>     problem and mostly the case if you need to allocate them in a bunch.

Also see the [comment above the declaration of the `allocate()` function](https://github.com/cacay/MemoryPool/blob/master/C-11/MemoryPool.h#L63):

> ```
> // Can only allocate one object at a time. n and hint are ignored
> pointer allocate(size_type n = 1, const_pointer hint = 0);
> ```

`std::vector` doesn't meet this constraint since it allocates memory as a single contiguous block required to fit at least `capacity()` elements. So it calls the `allocate()` function with `n` set to `capacity()`, but `MemoryPool` works as if `n=1` was passed in. The implementation of `MemoryPool` doesn't even provide a protection (in the form of an assertion) against such invalid use.

Comment: That makes sense, why I can't use a memory pool like that for `std::vector`. I know there's UB in this case, but I'm still suspect about how much memory is being used by the implementation. The source looked like there would be _less_ memory used, since a request for multiple type T's would result in just an allocation of 1.

Comment: As an add-on to my previous comment, I suspect that the vector would overwrite consecutive, unallocated slots in the memory pool, causing a corruption in the memory pool's tracking of free/used slots.