# Can I use one allocator instance for multiple vectors?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555087/can-i-use-one-memory-pool-for-multiple-vectors) about this topic, but the answer there is explaining why that certain memory pool implementation can't be used as allocator, without explaining whether another memory pool implementation can.
The problem is that vector takes allocator type, not object, which means that every vector will make and instance of allocator, which is inefficient if you need to make many vectors with low size. I want to use the same memory pool (ex: boost pool) for multiple vectors for fast and memory-efficient vectors.

Comment: Nothing says you can't have two (or more) razor-thin allocators that just make direct calls into the same underlying memory pool.

Comment: The memory pool, as mentioned by @DavidSchwartz, might be a `static` member of your allocator class, an approach retaining encapsulation as well (no other classes could interfere with).